# Android: back button issue or logical flow of program

Tags: android, back-button

i am trying to create a android application .In which i create two activities . In first activity user log in by click on button , and if he check a check box of keep me log in then next time when he came to its home page after logout then app keep remember his username and pass and if he did not logout(press logout button) in second activity then there thier is no way to reach to home page(first activity) . if he not logout then i want to stop user to reach home login page by using back press button or restart application.

Runprogram->enter login info -> next page->logout (This run ok)
Runprogram->enter login info -> next page -> press back press buttton -> then press logout button -> GOT ERROR (Force stop)

My problem is that when i press back press button and then click on logout button in second activity then Emmulator show me massage of unexpected close of application and force stop .Error in logcat window-

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(348): FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.example/com.example.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

My home page(first activity code is)=

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
EditText editText,editText1;
CheckBox checkBox;
int Requestcd=1;
String str,str1,str2,struser;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("computer" , MODE_PRIVATE);
    str = sharedPreferences.getString("key", "hold");
    if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("True") || str.equalsIgnoreCase("hold"))
    {
    editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1);
    editText1 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit2);
    checkBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check1);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            if(checkBox.isChecked())
            {
                str1 = editText.getText().toString();
                str2 = editText1.getText().toString();
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor1.putString("key1" , str1);
                editor1.putString("key2" , str2);
                editor1.commit();
            }
            struser = editText.getText().toString();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("key" , "false");
            editor.putString("key5" , struser);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this , Second.class );
            startActivityForResult(intent , Requestcd);
            editor.commit();
        }
    });

    }
    else
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this , Second.class );
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    String str13 = data.getExtras().getString("txt");
    String str14 = data.getExtras().getString("txt1");
    editText.setText(str13);
    editText1.setText(str14);
}
 }
```

My second Activity(welcome user and logout button ) code is=

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
* Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
* User: devendra
* Date: 18/1/13
* Time: 9:57 AM
* To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
*/
public class Second extends Activity{
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
String str, str1,str2,str3;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("computer" , MODE_PRIVATE);
    str3 = sharedPreferences.getString("key5" , "none");
    str = sharedPreferences.getString("key" , "null");
    Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2) ;
    TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
    textView.setText("Welcome"+" " +str3);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor1.putString("key", "True");
            str1 = sharedPreferences.getString("key1" , "Enter your username");
            str2 = sharedPreferences.getString("key2","Enter your password");
            editor1.remove("key1");
            editor1.remove("key2");

            Intent intent = new  Intent();
            intent.putExtra("txt",str1);
            intent.putExtra("txt1",str2);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            editor1.commit();
            finish();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("key" , "false");
    editor.commit();
    System.out.println("you in back press");
    if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("false"));
    {
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(Second.this , Second.class);
        startActivity(intent2);
    }
    finish();
}
 }
```

---

This is the complete error description from logcat window

```
{01-24 16:24:02.810: DEBUG/dalvikvm(382): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1   entries
01-24 16:24:04.702: INFO/dalvikvm(68): Jit: resizing JitTable from 1024 to 2048
01-24 16:24:04.750: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Displayed com.example/.MyActivity: +2s89ms
01-24 16:24:09.940: DEBUG/dalvikvm(147): GC_EXPLICIT freed 125K, 50% free 2990K/5895K,     external 5874K/7299K, paused 133ms
01-24 16:24:14.930: DEBUG/dalvikvm(242): GC_EXPLICIT freed 7K, 54% free 2544K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 92ms
01-24 16:24:20.030: DEBUG/dalvikvm(287): GC_EXPLICIT freed 503K, 55% free 2598K/5703K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 121ms
01-24 16:24:20.230: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.example/.Second } from pid 390
01-24 16:24:20.850: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Displayed com.example/.Second: +563ms
01-24 16:24:22.800: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(390): No keyboard for id 0
01-24 16:24:22.810: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(390): Using default keymap: /system  /usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-24 16:24:22.820: INFO/System.out(390): you in back press
01-24 16:24:22.830: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.example/.Second } from pid 390
01-24 16:24:22.830: WARN/ActivityManager(68): Duplicate finish request for HistoryRecord{406b1eb0 com.example/.Second}
01-24 16:24:23.520: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Displayed com.example/.Second: +673ms
01-24 16:24:26.340: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(390): Shutting down VM
01-24 16:24:26.340: WARN/dalvikvm(390): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-24 16:24:26.370: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.example/com.example.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2574)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:961)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.MyActivity.onActivityResult(MyActivity.java:69)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2528)
    ... 11 more
    01-24 16:24:26.380: WARN/ActivityManager(68): Force finishing activity com.example/.MyActivity
    01-24 16:24:26.920: WARN/ActivityManager(68): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{4061a9d0 com.example/.MyActivity}
    01-24 16:24:33.801: DEBUG/dalvikvm(320): GC_EXPLICIT freed 323K, 54% free 2539K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 104ms
    01-24 16:24:38.356: WARN/ActivityManager(68): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{4061a9d0 com.example/.MyActivity}
    01-24 16:24:38.702: WARN/ActivityManager(68): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{406ef998 com.example/.Second}
    01-24 16:24:50.600: INFO/Process(390): Sending signal. PID: 390 SIG: 9
    01-24 16:24:51.310: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Process com.example (pid 390) has died.
    01-24 16:24:51.320: INFO/WindowManager(68): WIN DEATH: Window{4069f500 com.example/com.example.MyActivity paused=false}
01-24 16:24:51.340: ERROR/InputDispatcher(68): channel '4055da70 com.example/com.example.Second (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
01-24 16:24:51.340: ERROR/InputDispatcher(68): channel '4055da70 com.example/com.example.Second (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
01-24 16:24:51.450: INFO/WindowManager(68): WIN DEATH: Window{4055da70 com.example/com.example.Second paused=false}}
```

Comment: please post complete stacktrace from logcat

Comment: @ben75 ben i just post logcat trace ......you can check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different values to identify how a call to `startActivityForResult()` was processed. On is the `requestCode` which identifies a `startActivityForResult()` call as you might have multiple of them. You used `Requestcd` as an identifier.

The second one is the `resultCode` which gives you an idea about the state of the result. If it has the value of `RESULT_OK`, the result was successfully set in the started activity. If you press the back button, the value would be `RESULT_CANCELED`.

In your case you need to check for both values and perform only when the `requestCode` and the `resultCode` is what you expect. If the values differ, you should think about doing some stuff to react on that. On possibility is to inform the user that the task he should have performed (for example: pick a picture) was cancelled.

Try the following code to read the data of the intent only if the result is set.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);                
    if (requestCode == Requestcd) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String str13 = data.getExtras().getString("txt");
            String str14 = data.getExtras().getString("txt1");
            editText.setText(str13);
            editText1.setText(str14);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would really prefer some description on why your code would fix the issue... This is nearly a code only answer...

Comment: Oh don't be too extensive with explaining words. Someone could be run into the trouble to learn something...

Comment: I voted down because there is a huge difference between answering and helping. You are just answering, but you don't help.

Comment: @SKT O my god you just solve my problem .....love you buddy ..my code run ok......please can you explain me how this solve my problem

Comment: @WarrenFaith I have explained the why this code might help. Was that useful.?

Comment: @dev Your back button was returning to previous intent and int MyActivity class on activity result method just tries to get the data from intent returned where no intent is being returned with data. Do always this check in on activity result method

Comment: Maybe you should have tried to explain it with some more words?!

Comment: Explaining in a comment is always a bad idea, too.

Comment: @WarrenFaith Agreed.. It was a bad way to make an answer. I should have made some descriptions. But anyway it helped the person and accepting your edit...

Comment: Sorry, I am not interested. I removed the down vote. Please invest some time if you want to answer. As you just saw beginners tend to copy & paste code and without an explanation they will never improve their skills.

Comment: @dev On Back button click you are ending the current activity by calling super.onBackPressed() function which goes to the first activity's onActivityResult method. Rest is in answer. If any doubt still persists feel free to ask

Comment: @SKT i just have only two doubts . 1 - how super.onBackpressed() send my activity to first activity's onActivityResult bcoz in backpress function i use intent(second activity to second activity) and how on back press result code change to Requestcanceled because i use setResult in onclick of logout button not on back button.   and one more onactivityresult method get data from where ?

Comment: @dev When you press back resultCode is set to RESULT_CANCELED unless you specify otherwise. Also super.onBackPressed() calls finish() for current activity. You are calling finish() again. Also to start an intent of same class you dont do like that

Intent intent= new Intent(Second.this, Second.class);
     startActivity(intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT));

and don't call finish() there

Comment: @dev and super.onBacPressed()